# Count number of words of specific type

Tags: tcl

I have a file having following data

```
Anny : dancing
Sonny : reciting
Joel : dancing
Anny : reciting
Anny : singing
```

I want the following o/p in tcl:

```
Anny -
singing 1
dancing 1
reciting 1

Joel -
dancing 1
```

I want to print in this format along with their count.

Comment: Where is your issue?

Comment: i tried using llength [regexp -all dancing Anny] but it does not seem to be working .it either matches once or none at all. I have dozens of similar occurences but the count is incorrect

Comment: How don't understand how your regexp could match.

Comment: I think you need something like *regexp -all {Anny\s\*:\s\*dancing} $file_content*, where *$file_content* is a variable that contains the searching text.

Comment: my count is still zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with Donal's answer, but using a single dictionary instead of an array of dictionaries:

```
set data [dict create]

set f [open yourinputfile.txt r]
while {[gets $f line] != -1} {
    if {[scan $line "%s : %s" who what] == 2} {
        dict update data $who activities {
            dict incr activities $what
        }
    }
}
close $f

dict for {who activities} $data {
    puts "$who -"
    dict for {what count} $activities {
        puts "$what $count"
    }
    puts ""
}
```

Comment: @donal, is there a reason why `dict incr` wasn't specified like `dict incr dictionaryVariable key ?key ...? ?increment?` -- was it the ambiguity about whether the last argument is a key or an increment?

Comment: Pretty. Thanks for showing that I have misread the `dict update` documentation all this time ;)

Comment: @glenn ..Thanks worked for me!! I tried using lsort -decreasing $count to get the list in decreasing order but it doesnt seem to work..is it not valid to use lsort in this case??

Comment: I tried putting count in a list and then sorting it but it doesnt seem to work. I have never tried sorting algorithms before and am going through them. Which sorting method can I use?

Comment: @johnny: ask a new question instead of adding subjects to this one.

Comment: @johnny, Since we can treat a dict like a list, we can replace `dict for {what count} $activities` with `foreach {what count} [lsort -stride 2 -index 1 -integer -decreasing $activities]`

Answer (score 1):

This is *really* about counting words, so we're going to be dealing with dictionaries — `dict incr` is a perfect tool for this — but you also need to do a bit of parsing. Parsing is done in many ways, but in this case `scan` can do what we want easily. (Remember when reading my code that the *result* of `scan` is the number of fields that it managed to satisfy.)

```
set f [open "yourinputfile.txt"]
set data [split [read $f] "\n"]
close $f

# Peel apart that data
foreach line $data {
    if {[scan $line "%s : %s" who what] == 2} {
        dict incr activity($who) $what
    }
}

# Now produce the output
foreach who [lsort [array names activity]] {
    puts "$who -"
    dict for {what count} $activity($who) {
        puts "$what $count"
    }
    # And the extra blank line
    puts ""
}
```

Comment: Hi  I tried the above code and it worked well for the 1st time but when i executed it again the value incremented twice .i.e adding to its previous value. Is there any such issue occuring to you also

Comment: the command dict for.. is not working for me it gives me iterative value at 1st and then the actual value

Comment: @johnny: (Regarding your "Hi I tried..." comment) You need to clear the counters before trying again. `unset activity` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an array to store the info while you're collecting in.

The *regexp* you're using is wrong.

Use a list of list to collect the matching in a pair way (i.e. word #n), and then assign all the collected matching to the proper key on the array.

Here is an example on how to do it:

```
set file_content {Anny : dancing
Sonny : reciting
Joel : dancing
Anny : reciting
Anny : singing
}

array set res {}

set anny {} 

lappend anny [list dancing [regexp -all {Anny\s*:\s*dancing} $file_content] ] 
lappend anny [list singing [regexp -all {Anny\s*:\s*singing} $file_content] ] 
lappend anny [list reciting [regexp -all {Anny\s*:\s*reciting} $file_content] ] 

set res(Anny) $anny

puts [array get res]
```

If I run this the output is:

> ```
> Anny {{dancing 1} {singing 1} {reciting 1}}
> ```

Now you could use the array to format the output as you wish.

Of course you should do the same with other names, so the best is to put the code inside a function.

Comment: It seems to me that you're missing the point: you should be parsing the file, not hardcoding all the names and activities in your code.

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it.

Count the number of different lines. Get rid of the colon.

```
foreach line [split $data \n] {
    dict incr d0 [string map {: {}} $line]
}
```

Convert the dictionary of lines and counts to a hierarchical dictionary with names on the highest level and activities on the next level. If `line` contains "Joel  dancing", the invocation below will be, after expansion with `{*}`: `dict set d1 Joel dancing 1`, creating the dictionary item `Joel {dancing 1}`.

```
dict for {line count} $d0 {
    dict set d1 {*}$line $count
}
```

Iterate over the dictionary and print the keys and values.

```
dict for {name activities} $d1 {
    puts "$name -"
    foreach {activity count} $activities {
        puts "$activity $count"
    }
    puts {}
}
```

Documentation:
[dict](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/dict.htm),
[foreach](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/foreach.htm),
[puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm),
[split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm),
[{*} (syntax)](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)